# Find the radius of convergence for infinite series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence

I have just shown via the Taylor expansion for $\sin(\frac{1}{n})$ that the series 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) $$

is in fact convergent and now I'm asked to find the radius of convergence for the series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\cdot x^n ,\; x\in\mathbb{R}$$

and I'm not sure how to approach this. I have tried the ratio test but it doesn't go well and the Cauchy-Hadamard doesn't seem to work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As $\frac1n-\sin\frac1n\sim \frac1{6n^3}$, we have
$$\frac1R=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac1n-\sin\frac1n}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac1{6n^3}}=1 $$

Comment: Ok so the Cauchy-Hadamard did in fact work, thanks.